# How to replace whole cell in pandas, with values from other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two DataFrames.

**df1:**

```
A    |    B    |    C
-----|---------|---------|
25zx | b(50gh) |         |
50tr | a(70lc) | c(50gh) |
```

**df2:**

```
  A  |  B
-----|-----
25zx |  T
50gh |  K
50tr |  K
70lc |  T
```

I want to replace values in `df1`. The row that I'm comparing is `df2['A']`, but the value that I want to put in to `df1` is value from the row `df['B']`. Note my goal is for new value to replace whole cell.

So the final table would look like:

**df3:**

```
A    |    B    |    C
-----|---------|---------|
  T  |    K    |         |
  K  |    T    |    K    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with optional parameter `regex=True` to replace the values in `df1` from the replacement series `s`:

```
s = pd.Series(df2['B'].values, index=r'.*?'+ df2['A'] + r'.*')
df3 = df1.replace(s, regex=True)
```

---

```
   A  B     C
0  T  K  None
1  K  T     K
```